# How to calculate a cumulative score with a LSTM using binary labels?

Tags: lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

So I might be missing something obvious here, but I'm new to LSTMs and I couldn't find anything on the internet that answers my question.

I need to use a few values (3 numerical values to be exact) to calculate a score which is used for binary classification. So my training dataset has binary labels. The score has to be cumulative, and not just based on the current values, and some values need to be remembered for longer than others. Therefore I decided to use a LSTM. My question is, what should be the basic architecture for such an LSTM? BTW the score should be a running score, i.e. it needs to be updated each time a new input comes in.

I'm using pyTorch, but I don't need exact code, just some guidance on how to design this network would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the input data and output labels. Few examples will help.

Comment: Yes. Of course. This is for a drowsiness calculator, and there would be 3 inputs coming in real time. They would be numbers between 0 and 1, and represent eye state (how open your eyes are), head pose (angle of your head) and yawning (how open your mouth is ). I want to use an LSTM because I want the system to have some sort of a memory and aumulate evidence on sleepiness, rather than triggering if someone blinks.  As you might imagine, things like yawning would have to be remembered for a longer duration, while things like eye state would require more immediate attention.

Comment: The input (the 3 values) would come in every 0.5 seconds during execution, but for training sets I have the value stored in an array. The labels would be drowsy or not drowsy. The final output I require are a label for each input set. Do let me know If you need further clarifications.

Comment: Example input - [0.34, 065, 0.55]      example output - drowsy